# Предупреждение системы безопасности TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, winapi, webbrowser

При выполнении `WebBrowser1.Navigate(Trim(edit1.Text))` программа выдает сообщение, что весьма раздражает и не удобно каждый раз разрешать выполнение((

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне автоматически без участия пользователя всегда разрешать выполнение?

Comment: Предупреждение не про js, а про сертификат.

Comment: Правильно выдаёт. В том и суть окошка, чтобы **уведомить пользователя**, что его могут или пытаются **взломать**. Скрыв его, вы сделаете только хуже.

Comment: Мне не скрывать нужно, а согласиться! Может это важно, я пытаюсь загрузить веб интерфейс сетевого принтера

Comment: в список доверенных сайтов добавить мб? это вам в настройки IE надо

Comment: Добавлял, но к сожалению не помогло((

Answer (score 0):

В итоге не нашел адекватного решения на Delphi и решил данный вопрос средствами AuotIt

Вот скрипт, может кому пригодится

```
$sTitle = 'Предупреждение системы безопасности' ;заголовок окна
$hWin = WinWait($sTitle, '', 5);ждем 5 сек. окно
If Not $hWin Then
    MsgBox(16, 'Error', 'Нет окна');если окна нет - сообщение об ошибке и выход
    Exit
EndIf
ControlClick($hWin, '', '[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]');клик по кнопке
```